# I can not build my project in android

Tags: android, angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

> transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 25.883 secs

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzab.class

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzab.class
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

i got this error while i'm trying to build in android with **cordova build android**

anyone have solution for build it?
i have ionic version - 3.2.0
cordova version - 7.0.1
nodejs - v7.10.0
npm - 4.6.1

all are latest versions installed all sdks are updated though i got error while build..

Comment: remove android platform. update google play services.add android and build again. This might work because some times our installed plugins require latest google play services and we didnt updated/installed in our android sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved it. it just a problem with android studio, android sdk build tool version 19.0.0 were required update and admob is the problem for crashing the app.

thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

> "duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzab.class",

You have included multiple versions of Google Mobile Services(gms) in your project. You might have to check your plugins in the project and ensure that only one version of gms is included in the project.